# NXP NFC Reader PNEV512R not working with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc, spi, mifare

NXP's NFC card reader PNEV512R (https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/nfc-readers/explore-nfc-exclusive-from-element14:PNEV512R) does not work with my new raspberry pi 4.

Kernel:

```
Linux AlexPi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Release:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"  
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux" VERSION_ID="10" 
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

For installing the needed software I followed this manual: https://github.com/svvitale/nxppy
Installation was without any fails. But even the instantiation of Mifare raises an exception.

Python Code:

```
import nxppy
mifare=nxppy.Mifare()
```

Exception:

```
nxppy.InitError: Nxppy: Unknown Error from Undefined Component

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "nfc.py", line 3, in <module>
            mifare=nxppy.Mifare()
    SystemError: <class 'nxppy.Mifare'> returned a result with an error set
```

The SPI was switched on of course. ^^ And I tested the interface with the loopbacktest: https://elinux.org/RPi_SPI
So SPI is working. On my Raspbarry Pi 3B+ everything works fine. Now I am looking for a solution to fix this problem.